# Trigger previous intent from current intent when pressing back button of device

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to trigger the previous activity in order to reload the whole page after updating some data in the current activity .

```
Ex: activity 1 = read data from database, display data
         = press button to proceed to intent 2
activity 2 = update/change data, save to database
         =  press back button of the device
activity 1 = no changes in the data
```

I thought that pressing the back button of the device will automatically reload the previous activity /page in order to reload all the data again. I don't know how to solve this problem since I'm new in android development and just experimenting. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1) Do not do in activity read data from database, read data from database set separate class
2) connects to the database and read / write data

if you need sorce tell me